# disable button based on promise

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-promise

I'm having trouble with disable button based on promise, my problem is when promise is evaluated and returns it value, it is reevaluated and it's in an infinite loop:

```
<button [disabled] = "(isDisabled('myEmail@email.com') | async)">                      
    <mat-icon>
       delete
    </mat-icon>
</button>

isDisabled(email: string): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(this.emailAllowed !== email)
    });
}
```

It have to be a promise because my method is more complex and comes from promise.

How can I say something like "evaluate the promise just once"?

I tried using "as", but it makes an error:

```
<button [disabled] = "(isDisabled('myEmail@email.com') | async) as isDisabled">
```

Comment: why don't you call isDisabled in component and set a variable base on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i suggest a simpler way to update disabled based on start or resolving promise,

in html:

```
[attr.disabled]="state"
```

and in your promise change value of `state`.

Answer (score 3):

`Disabled` attribute accepts only boolean value, and your method is returning a Promise.

You need to update your method to return boolean.

```
    isDisabled(email: string): boolean {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(this.emailAllowed !== email)
    });
}
```

Comment: I need to use a promise, my method is more complex than this

Comment: Assuming this method is in your component, need not return Promise